# How would microfrontend work using Apache Wicket?

Tags: security, iframe, wicket, basic-authentication, micro-frontend

I want to achieve microfrontend architecture using Apache Wicket but I cannot make it work.

```
add(new WebMarkupContainer("testFrame") {

        @Override
        protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag) {
            checkComponentTag(tag, "iframe");

            super.onComponentTag(tag);
            //Won't work like this if you want to send credentials.
            //tag.put("src", "http://localhost:8089/httpBasicAuthenticated/url/page/");

        }

        @Override
        public void onComponentTagBody(MarkupStream markupStream, ComponentTag openTag) {
            Response response = getRequestCycle().getResponse();

            final CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();

            String username = "user";
            String password = "password";

            final UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);

            provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

            final HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider).build();
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            String body = "";
            try {
                httpResponse = client.execute(new 
                   HttpGet("http://localhost:8089/httpBasicAuthenticated/url/page/"));
                body = IOUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8");
            } catch (final IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            response.write(body);

        }

    });
```

[Result from inspecting the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onagY.png)

I am trying out with an iframe but it's not rendering the page inside the iframe. Is there something wrong? How would I send the credentials on request of the page through iframe?

**EDIT:**
In this code, I'm trying to send the credentials automatically so that the authentication prompt doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

With basic authentication you need to render `<iframe src="..."></iframe>` and the browser will show you a dialog to enter the credentials.

If you construct the body at the server (i.e. in Wicket code) then you don't need an iframe, but a `div`.

Comment: I wanted to send the credentials automatically without needing the authentication prompt. I just edited my description. I could do it with `Include` but that means I need to bring the page's web resources e.g. css, js files and add it to the head section but what if the url's `<link>`s and `<script>` have relative url's. Which I think it's cumbersome, any suggestion? I'm happy to hear more.